# Is MPLS a total different network then internet?

Tags: routing, router, mpls, mpls-vpn

If I need to connect my two sites through a secured MPLS connection and I call a service provider to install one for me so will they connect me to a total different network cloud where they have only LSRs ruuning or do they use the common network through which the whole traffic pass.

Comment: Questions about networks which are no under your control are explicitly off-topic. This is a question only your ISP can answer.

Comment: so are there routers which work as label switched router and general IP routing together?

Comment: Questions by end users of a network not within their control or of a service provider network are considered off topic by this community. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most providers use the same network backbone for their MPLS traffic as their regular Internet traffic but your MPLS traffic is private and takes priority over Internet traffic.

Comment: so do they use the same router for IP routing and label switched routing? I  have no idea what the ISPs use. My question is in general sense that is there any kind of router exist which do both the work ip routing and label routing?